# Why an infinite loop with: while ( [managedObjectContext hasChanges] ) [managedObjectContext processPendingChanges]

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Should the following while statement not exit after a maximum of one execution?

```
while ( [self.managedObjectContext hasChanges] )
    [self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
```

Comment: If you want to execute it just once, then you could have used `if()` inplace of `while`.

Comment: I know, but the point is that I am trying to process the pending changes. The code above is to see if `-processPendingChanges` actually  does what I hope it does. In that case, `-hasChanges` should become FALSE. But unfortunately, this test points out that I don't really understand what's going on... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasChanges` remains true while the context has changes that have not been flushed to disk.  What you're looking for is `save:`, which will call through to `processPendingChanges` in addition to writing changes in the context to disk and altering the changed state of the context.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Any way to see if `-processPendingChanges` did its work properly? For some reason, my code gets a Notification twice with only one edit.

Comment: I don't think it modifies any variables you can observe.  `hasChanges` is KVO-able, though.

Comment: Not sure how I can make use of this. I posted a new question that describes my actual issue a bit more elaborately at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997558/observing-changes-in-the-properties-of-an-nsmanagedobject-how-to-avoid-looping.