# Observing changes in the properties of an NSManagedObject: how to avoid looping?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsnotificationcenter

In my application, I observe the properties of a  managed object. A change may lead to adjustments in some of its other properties, so the managed object itself receives a message of a changed property. These changes happen through bindings that are set up in the Interface Builder.

I have the following method in the implementation of the managed object:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ( !processingChange )
    {
        processingChange = YES;

        *** DO STUFF TO THIS MANAGED OBJECT'S PROPERTIES ***

        [self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];

        processingChange = NO;
        return;
    }
}
```

The `processingChange` boolean is there to avoid an endless "notification loop", but it is not working as I expect (plus it looks like a real dirty hack).

There must be another way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use MOMs' `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` it doesnt generate KVOs

Comment: If my managed object is an EventType, can I add a new Event to its to-many relationship without generating KVO messages? `-addEventsObject`?

Comment: I think you need to set the underlying set to avoid KVO

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to send the notification "by hand", take a look: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i

> The observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: method is
>   automatically invoked when the value of an observed property is
>   changed in a KVO-compliant manner, or if a key upon which it depends
>   is changed.

Maybe this is even the mistake?

Comment: This looks really promising, I can tell at least that I had not realized that this would happen. Perhaps I called `-observeValueForKeyPath:` twice. I'll see if I can get the method to be called without manual notification!

Comment: I think I misread the answer, and perhaps I was unclear about the way I have it set up. I am observing changes in the managed object, which happen through bindings in the Interface Builder. I am not sending manual notifications and I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: sorry but how is this related?

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Look at the question's edit history (and the questioner's comments on this answer). This answer was written for the original version of the question.